# Serilog logging to elasticsearch, long delay, is a configuration available for logging faster

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, serilog

I'm in the process of converting a small project from `log4net` to `serilog` using the `elasticsearch` sink and `rolling file` sink. I have noticed that when logging to the `elasticsearch` sink it takes a long time before it appears in elasticsearch. By long time I mean that  many lines of code are executed before the log statement appears in `elasticsearch`. This is however not the case for the log file.

I have stepped through my code, so it isn't a delay with logging within the `elastisearch` "db", but rather a delay in the sink to deliver it.
Considering this I'm a little afraid of loosing valuable log statements towards the elasticsearch, when the application fails, due to the delay. I do have the file as a backup, but it would be nice to be able to trust that the `elasticsearch` sink doesn't loose logs.

I have looked for information of what delay could be expected, but couldn't find any information.
Furthermore, I also looked for a configuration for the sink to log faster, but no luck.

**What I'm looking for is a configuration setting that can reduce the delay in the `elasticsearch` sink ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use: `Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch` and set `batchPostingLimit` to **5**

See in : https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

Comment: I'm already using the ElasticSearch sink, just want to make sure that I understand this setting correctly as it doesn't seem to be documented. Is this the number of log statements that can be handle before emptying an internal buffer to elasticsearch ?

Comment: In this file you will find the description of each property related to the buffer. https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch/blob/f14e29ffd8eb1b536efd9b5e8e150b60f49971ec/src/Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch/Sinks/ElasticSearch/ElasticsearchSinkOptions.cs